# Cannot understand what web service is expecting

Tags: php, web-services, soap, wsdl, laravel-5

I have to connect to a Web Service and call a function, but always show this error:

The webservice has this WSDL:
https://www1.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/NFeDistribuicaoDFe.asmx?WSDL

The Error:

**SOAPFault: Server was unable to process request. ---> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**

I´m not expert in it, but the function expects a xml and i´m passing like this one:

```
<distDFeInt xmlns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe" versao="1.00">
    <tpAmb>1</tpAmb>
    <cUFAutor>35</cUFAutor>
    <CNPJ>12345678912345</CNPJ>
    <distNSU>
        <ultNSU>000000000000000</ultNSU>
    </distNSU>
</distDFeInt>
```

And this is my code:

```
      $context = [
        'ssl' => [
          'verify_peer' => false,
          'verify_peer_name' => false,
          `enter code here`'allow_self_signed' => true
        ]
      ];

      $context = [
      'ssl' => [
              'verify_peer' => false,
              'verify_peer_name' => false,
              'allow_self_signed' => true
        ]
    ];

    $params = [
      'local_cert' => $path_certificado,
      'passphrase'=> '123456',
      'uri' => 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe', // target namespace
      'location' => 'https://www1.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/NFeDistribuicaoDFe.asmx', // is the URL of the remote Web service
      'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
      'soapaction' => 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/nfeDistDFeInteresse',
      'stream_context' => stream_context_create($context),
      'use' => SOAP_LITERAL
    ];

    try {
      $client = new \SoapClient(null, $params);
      $xml = self::createXml();

      $client->__soapCall('nfeDistDFeInteresse', [$xml], ['soapaction' => 'http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/nfeDistDFeInteresse', 'Host' => 'www1.nfe.fazenda.gov.br', 'Content-Type' => ' text/xml; charset=utf-8', 'Content-Length' => 'length']);

      return $client;
    } catch (SoapFault $e) {
      echo $e;
    }
```

The wsdl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <wsdl:definitions xmlns:s="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:http="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/http/" xmlns:mime="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/mime/" xmlns:tns="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:tm="http://microsoft.com/wsdl/mime/textMatching/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" targetNamespace="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe" xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/">
      <wsdl:types>
        <s:schema elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe">
          <s:element name="nfeDistDFeInteresse">
            <s:complexType>
              <s:sequence>
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="nfeDadosMsg">
                  <s:complexType mixed="true">
                    <s:sequence>
                      <s:any />
                    </s:sequence>
                  </s:complexType>
                </s:element>
              </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
          </s:element>
          <s:element name="nfeDistDFeInteresseResponse">
            <s:complexType>
              <s:sequence>
                <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="nfeDistDFeInteresseResult">
                  <s:complexType mixed="true">
                    <s:sequence>
                      <s:any />
                    </s:sequence>
                  </s:complexType>
                </s:element>
              </s:sequence>
            </s:complexType>
          </s:element>
        </s:schema>
      </wsdl:types>
      <wsdl:message name="nfeDistDFeInteresseSoapIn">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:nfeDistDFeInteresse" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:message name="nfeDistDFeInteresseSoapOut">
        <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:nfeDistDFeInteresseResponse" />
      </wsdl:message>
      <wsdl:portType name="NFeDistribuicaoDFeSoap">
        <wsdl:operation name="nfeDistDFeInteresse">
          <wsdl:input message="tns:nfeDistDFeInteresseSoapIn" />
          <wsdl:output message="tns:nfeDistDFeInteresseSoapOut" />
        </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:portType>
      <wsdl:binding name="NFeDistribuicaoDFeSoap" type="tns:NFeDistribuicaoDFeSoap">
        <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="nfeDistDFeInteresse">
          <soap:operation soapAction="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/nfeDistDFeInteresse" style="document" />
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap:body use="literal" />
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:binding>
      <wsdl:binding name="NFeDistribuicaoDFeSoap12" type="tns:NFeDistribuicaoDFeSoap">
        <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
        <wsdl:operation name="nfeDistDFeInteresse">
          <soap12:operation soapAction="http://www.portalfiscal.inf.br/nfe/wsdl/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/nfeDistDFeInteresse" style="document" />
          <wsdl:input>
            <soap12:body use="literal" />
          </wsdl:input>
          <wsdl:output>
            <soap12:body use="literal" />
          </wsdl:output>
        </wsdl:operation>
      </wsdl:binding>
      <wsdl:service name="NFeDistribuicaoDFe">
        <wsdl:port name="NFeDistribuicaoDFeSoap" binding="tns:NFeDistribuicaoDFeSoap">
          <soap:address location="https://www1.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/NFeDistribuicaoDFe.asmx" />
        </wsdl:port>
        <wsdl:port name="NFeDistribuicaoDFeSoap12" binding="tns:NFeDistribuicaoDFeSoap12">
          <soap12:address location="https://www1.nfe.fazenda.gov.br/NFeDistribuicaoDFe/NFeDistribuicaoDFe.asmx" />
        </wsdl:port>
      </wsdl:service>
    </wsdl:definitions>
```

What i´m doing wrong? Thank´s

Comment: Please include into your question,  at least the fragment of the WSDL describing the service. Opening the url gives 403 error and, if that system changes, the question loses context.

Comment: @Alfabravo. I edited the question including the wsdl

Comment: Don't know on Laravel, but standard SoapClient usage requires you to call the operation by doing `$client->nfeDistDFeInteresse(new SoapVar($xml, XSD_ANYXML))`. Also, SoapClient creation could include URL instead of the operation call... Tried that already?

Comment: @Alfabravo Did not work!

Comment: @Alfabravo, this code works :) `$result = $client->nfeDistDFeInteresse(['nfeDadosMsg' => new \SoapVar($xml, SOAP_ENCODED)]);`. Thank you, because of your answers show me the way.

Comment: Glad it worked! Please add your finding as an answer and accept it so others can see the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
$result = $client->nfeDistDFeInteresse(['nfeDadosMsg' => new \SoapVar($xml, SOAP_ENCODED)]);
```